# Multi Alert Javascript With Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question, when I try to multi alert, I see all results is same (all data is "1"). I want:

- if click on button number1 => alert : 1
- if click on button number2 => alert : 2
- if click on button number3 => alert : 3

I attach a photo about my problem

[image]

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>constructor-selector</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 1. Define some markup -->
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="1">Copy</button>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="2">Copy</button>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="3">Copy</button>

    <!-- 2. Include library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 3. Instantiate clipboard by passing a string selector -->

 <script>
 var clipboard = new Clipboard('button');
 
 clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var test = $(".btn").attr("data-clipboard-text");
  alert (test + " : was copy on clipboard");
 });

 clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
var test = $(".btn").attr("data-clipboard-text");
```

with this

```
var test = e.text;
```

Once Clipboard is instantiated and a `copy` event has been successful, then the event's text `e.text` is basically the value of `data-clipboard-text` attribute of the button clicked.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.6.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>constructor-selector</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 1. Define some markup -->
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="1">Copy</button>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="2">Copy</button>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="3">Copy</button>


    <!-- 3. Instantiate clipboard by passing a string selector -->

 <script>
    // instantiate Clipboard
 var clipboard = new Clipboard('button');
 // once text is copied to clipboard
 clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        // event action "copy"
        // event text "e.text" now has the value of data-clipboard-text attribute
  //console.log(e);
  var test = e.text;
  alert (test + " : was copy on clipboard");
 });

 clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
 
 clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var test = e.text;
  alert (test + " : was copy on clipboard");
 });

 clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.6.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="1">Copy</button>
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="2">Copy</button>
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="3">Copy</button>
```